# Compose Futures with Recovery in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a method, that performs some async actions. Every async action need a recovery. How can I write the method in more composable fashion?

Pseudo scala code:

```scala
object Test {

  import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  case class ObjectData(
                         internal: String,
                         external1: String = "",
                         external2: String = ""
                       )

  case class ObjectInfo(
                         id: String,
                         internal: String,
                         external1: String = "",
                         external2: String = ""
                       )

  def addObject(data: ObjectData): Future[ObjectInfo] = {
    internalActionWithRollback(data.internal) { objectInfo =>
      externalActionWithRollback(objectInfo.id, data.external1) {
        externalActionWithRollback(objectInfo.id, data.external2) {
          Future.successful(
            objectInfo.copy(
              external1 = data.external1,
              external2 = data.external2
            )
          )
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private def internalActionWithRollback[R](internal: String)
                                           (nextAction: ObjectInfo => Future[R]): Future[R] = ???

  private def externalActionWithRollback[R](id: String, external: String)
                                           (nextAction: => Future[R]): Future[R] = ???

}
```

**Edit:**

@IvanKurchenko helped me to solve the problem.
We need future wrapper with `flatMap` and `map` functions:

```scala
object TransactFuture {
  implicit class FutureOps[T, R](underling: Future[T]) {
    def rollbackWith(rollback: PartialFunction[Throwable, Future[R]]): TransactFuture[T, R] = {
      new TransactFuture[T, R](underling, rollback)
    }
    def empty: TransactFuture[T, R] = {
      new TransactFuture[T, R](underling, PartialFunction.empty[Throwable, Future[R]])
    }
  }

}

class TransactFuture[T, R](underlying: Future[T], rollback: PartialFunction[Throwable, Future[R]]) {

  private def recoveryInternal[S](implicit ec: ExecutionContext): PartialFunction[Throwable, Future[S]] = {
    case ex: Throwable =>
      val failed = Future.failed[S](ex)
      rollback.lift(ex).fold(failed)(_.flatMap[S](_ => failed))
  }

  def flatMap[S](f: T => Future[S])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[S] = {
    underlying.flatMap(f).recoverWith(recoveryInternal)
  }
  def map[S](f: T => S)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[S] = {
    underlying.map(f).recoverWith(recoveryInternal)
  }
}
```

With this wrapper we can write the main function:

```scala
  def addObject(data: ObjectData): Future[ObjectInfo] = {
    for {
      objectInfo <- addObjectInternal(internal)
      _ <- addExternal(objectInfo.id, data.external1)
        .rollbackWith({
          case _: Throwable => deleteObjectInternal(objectInfo.id)
        })
      _ <- addExternal(objectInfo.id, data.external2)
        .rollbackWith({
          case _: Throwable => deleteExternal(objectInfo.id)
        })
    } yield {
      objectInfo.copy(
        external1 = data.external1,
        external2 = data.external2
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by recovery? Some action that will make sure that if future failed then it will be retried or fixed to success? Or (judging by the name rollback) it should somehow revert the effects of failed future computation?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Thank you for your question. Well, in general you can use Future's recover or recoverWith methods, or do you have concerns regarding them?

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Yes, recovery should revert the effect if the next async action failed.

Comment: @IvanKurchenko I use recoverWith. But with it I cannot use for-comprehensions for compose the actions. I have to use next action as an argument. The code looks ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to invoke some action, if child or next `Future` execution failed. It seems this behavior similar to some kind of transaction. 
Well, `Future` out of the box does not provide such behavior, but some wrapper can be implemented instead:

```scala
class TransactFuture[T](underlying: Future[T], rollback: PartialFunction[Throwable, Future[Unit]]) {
  def flatMap[S](f: T => Future[S])(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Future[S] = {
    underlying.flatMap(f).recoverWith {
      case exception: Throwable =>
        val failure = Future.failed[S](exception)
        rollback.lift(exception).fold(failure)(_.flatMap(_ => failure))
    }
  }
}

// Just provides syntax sugar over Future
implicit class FutureOps[T](underling: Future[T]) {
  def rollbackWith(rollback: PartialFunction[Throwable, Future[Unit]]): TransactFuture[T] = {
    new TransactFuture[T](underling, rollback)
  }
}
```

Which can be used in the next way:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val action = for {
  _ <- Future.successful(println("A executed")).rollbackWith {
    case _: Throwable => Future.successful(println("A recovered"))
  }
  _ <- Future.successful(println("B executed")).rollbackWith {
    case _: Throwable => Future.successful(println("B recovered"))
  }
  _ <- Future.failed(new Exception("C failed"))
} yield ()

Await.result(action, 1 second)
```

So the result output will be:

```
A executed
B executed
B recovered
A recovered
Exception in thread "main" ......
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: C failed
```

Hope this helps!